# linear system straight line solution

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a matrix

$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 3 \\
0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$

I have obtained the Eigenvalues $\lambda = -2$ and $\lambda = -1$.

Now, after trying to find the straight line solution for $\lambda = -1$, I get:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$

...

Now what does it mean?
$ 3y = 0, -y = 0$, but what is the eigenvector ? ? ?

Can it be a vector (0,1) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You showed that $A\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=-\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$ if and only if $y=0$.

Thus the set of eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $-1$ is $\{(x,0)\mid x\ne0\}$ and the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $-1$ is $E_{-1}=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$. Note that $E_{-1}$ is the subspace generated by the vector $(1,0)$.

Comment: Funny downvote. Purely based on mathematical reasons, for sure.

Answer (score -3):

$3y=0$ and $-y=0$ implies $y=0$. For a linear transformation $T$ representing the matrix, $\IM T = \{(0,0)\}$ for every $x$.
So for every $x,y$ you get $(0,0)$.
Therefore you get as the $\KER T=\{(1,0)\}$.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}\DeclareMathOperator{\KER}{Ker}$

Comment: So that means that one of the straight line solution is 0 ?

Comment: yes, one is the vector 0

Comment: No, for every $x,y$ you get $y=0$ while $x$ can be anything.

Comment: Yes, and that's why (0,0) is a solution.

Comment: by the way.. this is exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, sure $(0,0)$ is a solution, but it does not define a line, does it? $(0,0)$ is always an element of the kernel of a matrix, but the more interesting element in this case is $(1,0)$.

Comment: yes! and thats why I wrote KerT = (1,0)!!